# cannot see some data after scraping a link using requests.get or scrapy

Tags: web-scraping, python-requests, scrapy

I am trying to scrape data from [a stock exchange website](http://www.tsetmc.com/Loader.aspx?ParTree=151311&i=7745894403636165). Specifically, I need to read numbers in the top left table. If you inspect the html page, you will see these numbers under `<div>` tags, following `<td>` tags whose `id` is `"e0"`, `"e3"`, `"e1"` and `"e4"`. However, the reponse, once saved into a text file, lacks all these numbers and some others. I have tried using selenium with some 20 second delays (so that the javascript is loaded) but this does not work and the element cannot be found.
Is there any workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use inspect element > network > filter by XHR, you will see the page which sends the data :

[image: inspect element network results]

In your case this is this link : `http://www.tsetmc.com/tsev2/data/instinfofast.aspx?i=7745894403636165&c=23%20`.

Unfortunately for you, the data is badly arranged so you will have to look at which position in the answer is the data which interests you. Good luck.

Comment: @@Torpedo Great. I now see the data. But two more questions: 1. How can I extract this link from XHR part of pages like this using scraping tech.? 2. There are some titles in the page that do not appear neither in requests.get() 's response nor in the link from XHR. Where are they and how are they sent to the landing page?